# Why does Yarn say "Found incompatible module" when the version is correct?

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

When I run `yarn`, I receive the following error:

```
yarn install v0.16.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error recursive-iterator@2.0.1: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=6.0.0".
error Found incompatible module
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

However, the version of Node that I have installed is `v6.9.2-pre`, which seems to be correct for the version range. Any ideas why I get this error?

Comment: This seems to be a tag mismatch, she is talking about facebook's yarn. So no need to close.

Comment: ah.. wrong tag, sorry

Comment: no idea why I got this error too, but I by-passed it by using `yarn install --ignore-engines`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After upgrading to current tag `v7.0.0` and node -v `v7.0.0` yarn work just fine. I think, this problem related to `-pre` release versions or maybe just about the prefix inside of the version output.

Answer (score 2):

To upgrade node in mac

```
 brew upgrade node
```